# How do I correctly require a dependency plugin in Moodle 3.5

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, moodle, moodle-api

I  have an activity  plugin  that  requires  another  plugin to work  correctly. 
I followed  the recommendation of  requesting this plugin as a dependency  in the  version.php  file like this :

```
$plugin->dependencies = array('local_aws' => 2017071501 ); //AWS php SDK  dependency
```

The  problem is  when I  install my plugin   I receive a   Warning :

> Warning:
>   require_once(/var/www/moodle/local/aws/sdk/aws-autoloader.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/moodle/mod/tutorship/lib.php on line 37
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/moodle/local/aws/sdk/aws-autoloader.php'
>   (include_path='/var/www/moodle/lib/pear:.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/moodle/mod/mymodulep/lib.php **on line 37**

Line  37  uses  this  code:

```
// For AWS API Part
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/local/aws/sdk/aws-autoloader.php');
```

So it seems  to me  during the install   of my  plugin the  require_ once  is  not  being  satisfied  as  the AWS  plugin has  yet  to be installed.  Well I  followed  the  recommendation of  making it  a dependency in version.php   but  it isn't  being installed  before the require_ once  is checked ?

How  can   I resolve  this  conundrum ?

Comment: I bundled the plugin  within mine and  changed  the path to my  plugin  not to local.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right in your supposition that "require_ once is not being satisfied as the AWS plugin has yet to be installed". To avoid this kind of problem, you should try to avoid to require files of other plugins/libraries in lines that are actually executed during the plugin installation/upgrading procedures. Is it necessary to use the other plugin during the installation of yours?

I would move the `require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/local/aws/sdk/aws-autoloader.php');` to some file that is never run during the actual installation/upgrading (avoid the header of lib.php). For example, I would create a class `mod/tutorship/classes/some_class.php` (properly "namespaced" with `namespace mod_tutorship;`), do the require_once there and then just instantiate the class in my lib.php **within the function** that actually needs it.